# Replacing fragment does not work properly

Tags: java, android

I am replacing an fragment with the following code. Why isn't `onCreateView` invoked immediately after the commit? I am executing a Async task after this, however I get a nullpointerexception since the references in ResultListFragment is not resolved yet since the `OnCreateView` method hasn't been runned. Why? and how could I fix this?

```
if (mResultListFragment == null) {
    mResultListFragment = new ResultListFragment<Question>();
}

getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .addToBackStack("result")
    .replace(R.id.someContainer, mResultListFragment)
    .commit();

// AsyncTask stuff here
```

Comment: can you post your full code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `FragmentManager`'s [`executePendingTransaction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29) to block the main thread until your fragment has been committed, without calling this the commit is done asynchronously

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the answer. I was reading about it at the same time you answered:)